# How to read data from application(in tables) of a webpage and then write it in excel?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, report

Should I use array as a medium to store the read data and then write it in excel?
Have to carry out the following steps:
1. There are some data on Page1 of the application: Need to read that data
2. Write that data in an excel sheet.
3. Print action on Page2 leads to a Report generation.
4. Assert those printed data with excel.

Please suggest. Thanks

1st step:
Reading data from application, and storing in list.

```
List< WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.xpath(some path));
              for(WebElement e : myList){
                System.out.println(e.getText());
            }

2nd step: How to write this data to excel?
```

Comment: 1. Data in list from appliaction

Answer (score 0):

you can use list to store the data from the application.

List myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);

Answer (score 0):

Use Map with type String and List

```
Map<String, List<String>> tableMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>();
```